# AJAX pagination in Zend Framework

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, pagination, helper

How do you display AJAX paginated data using Zend_Framework?

- Are there any good examples using `paginationControl()`, `ajaxLink()` and `ajaxContext()` helpers?
- Would you share your implementation?

Comment: AjaxLink is not suitable to use with paginators. I just wrote my own jQuery actions to attach the ajax actions to the pagination links.

Comment: These links are a must read for such requirement : 

[Phil Brown's Blog](http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2011/03/awesome-pagination-with-zf-paginator-ajaxcontext-and-the-html5-history-api/)

[youtube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrw8TP62-XU&feature=BFa&list=PLC7FDFC7E0F370A02)

[zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext)

Answer (score 2):

you can use table with simple paginations with :
https://www.datatables.net/

### Here is an example :

controller :

```
<?php
class ExampleController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->view->headTitle()->append('Example');
        //populate database tables
        $example = new Application_Model_ExampleMapper();
        $this->view->entries = $example->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

view :

```
<script>         
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
</script>
<table class="display dataTable" id="exampledtable" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Field1</th>
                    <th>Field2</th>
                    <th>Field3</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
         <tbody><?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $this->escape($entry->ID) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->escape($entry->field1) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->escape($entry->field2) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->escape($entry->field3) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```